# Saving the Tokens into ArraysList and compare each in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, token

i am working on plagiarism detection system for that i need to compare two strings and show the similarity result.

I have two strings i have converted them into tokens separated with the spaces, now i want to save them in ArrayList, so that i can compare them and show the the result of same index in sequence.

My Source code is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    String str1 = "This is String number one";
    String str2 = "This is String number two";

    StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(str1);
    StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(str2);

    System.out.println("---Split by space---");
    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

    list1.add(str1);

// was trying to save the tokens in arraylist...

    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list2.add(str2);

    for (String number : list1) {
System.out.println("String 1 = " + number);
}
    for (String number : list2) {
System.out.println("String 2 = " + number);
}

}
}
```

Any Suggestions/Examples would be helpful.

Comment: OK, so what's your question specifically?

Comment: So basically you want compare x position element in both list1 and list2 and store into 3rd list with same index as x ? is it right ?

Comment: i want to convert two strings into tokens save them in arraylist separately and compare two arraylist to found out the similarity.

Comment: @pcj

i am working on plagiarism detection system for that i need to compare two strings and show the similarity result.

Comment: @MohsinRasheed If your question isn't clear; don't write comments, **update** your question instead. Besides ... how you name your variables isnt exactly great. "str1" and "st1" look pretty similar ... avoid those short names; use names that say what the object is actually used for.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the StringTokenizer?

```
 String str1 = "This is String number one";
 String str2 = "This is String number two";

 List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(str1.split(" "));
 List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList(str2.split(" "));
```

Comment: I agree; StringTokenizer is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the tokens to your list, you have to iterate over them, not simply add the StringTokenizer to your list.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str1 = "This is String number one";
    StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(str1);
    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Iterate over all tokens and add them to your list
    while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
        list1.add(st1.nextToken());
    }

    System.out.println("List 1 tokens: ");
    for (String element : list1) {
        System.out.println("\t" + element);
    }

    System.out.println("There are " + list1.size() + " tokens");
}
```

The output is:

```
List 1 tokens: 
    This
    is
    String
    number
    one
There are 5 tokens
```

Comment: griFlo also posted a good answer. Just keep in mind java.util.Arrays.ArrayList and java.util.ArrayList are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet will help you:--

```
List<String> repetWords = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    String str1 = "This is String number one";
    String str2 = "This is String number two";

    String[] array = str1.split(" ");
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(array.length);
    Collections.addAll(list, array);

    String[] array2 = str2.split(" ");
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(array2.length);
    Collections.addAll(list2, array2);

    for (String string : list) {
        if(list2.indexOf(string) != -1){
            repetWords.add(string);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("repeated words in str2");

    for (String rptWords : repetWords) {
        System.out.println(rptWords);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not using the string tokenizers st1 and st2 , you are adding Strings str1,str2 to your arraylistlist.I am not sure what u r trying to achieve with the code but from ur comment ***" // was trying to save the tokens in arraylist..."*** and then adding the string to list instead of all items in the string tokenizer variable

Change this part of your code

```
// was trying to save the tokens in arraylist...

    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list2.add(str2);
```

to

```
 // was trying to save the tokens in arraylist...  
  ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
     while((st2.hasMoreTokens()))//you need to iterate over the string tokens
        list2.add(str2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
for (String token1 : list1) {
            for (String token2 : list2) {
                // code to compare two tokens
            }
        }
```

Also if you want to compare same index elements then both the lists should have same size :

```
for (int index = 0; index <list1.size(); index++) {
            String token1 = list1.get(index);
            String token2 = list2.get(index);
            // code to compare tokens
        }
```

Comment: The top block, with nested for loops, is seriously wrong.  It will compare item 0 from the first list with *every* item in the second list.  Then it will compare item 1 in the first list with *every* item in the second list.  And assuming both lists will be the same length is very naive, resulting in brittle code.

Comment: @Terrible Tadpole 15 this is how exactly i intended, for case where he may need to compare each element with elements of other list.

Comment: Okay.  But that's probably worth mentioning in your answer, given the level of expertise demonstrated by the code in the original question.  The original poster might not pick up what you intended without an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This does everything you seem to be asking for, and it also copes with lists of different lengths:

```
public class StringTokenCompare {

    void compareStringTokens (String s1, String s2) {
        List <String> l1 = Arrays.asList (s1.split (" "));
        List <String> l2 = Arrays.asList (s2.split (" "));
        Iterator <String> i1 = l1.iterator();
        Iterator <String> i2 = l2.iterator();
        int totalItems = Math.abs (l1.size () - l2.size ());
        int matchCount = 0;
        while (i1.hasNext() && i2.hasNext()) {
            String t1 = i1.next();
            String t2 = i2.next();
            if (t1.equals(t2)) {
                ++matchCount;
            }
        }
        System.out.format ("Tokens in longer line: %d", totalItems);
        System.out.format ("Matching tokens:       %d", matchCount);
    }

}
```

**BUT**, the fact that the lists may be of different sizes should start you thinking about issues that you have to cope with if you're serious about detecting plagiarism.

1. What if a word has been inserted or deleted so it shifts the words in one of the lists?  You'll get a low match count on very similar lines.
2. What if the word order has been rearranged?

My suggestion - beyond the scope of the original question of course - is that you should seriously consider **edit distance** between the token lists rather than a naive item-by-item comparison.  An Internet search will quickly locate a simple edit distance algorithm.